# Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity and Not sure how to handle insert method's return type Errors

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dao

I'm learning Android room database and I have been struggling with the error giving below for 2 days now:

```
error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> $completion);
error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
    public abstract java.lang.Object insertCard(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
error: Not sure how to handle delete method's return type. Currently the supported return types are void, int or Int.
    public abstract java.lang.Object deleteCard(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
                                     ^
                                                        ^
error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> $completion);
                                                        ^
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "card_table")
data class Card (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id : Int,
    val BIN : String,
    @Embedded
    val cardInfo : CardInfo
    )

data class CardInfo(
    @Embedded
    val  bank: Bank,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_brand")
    val  brand: String?,
    @Embedded
    val  country: Country,
    @Embedded
    val  number: Number,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_prepaid")
    val  prepaid: Boolean?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_scheme")
    val  scheme: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_type")
    val  type: String?
)

data class Bank(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "bank_city")
    val  city: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "bank_name")
    val  name: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "bank_phone")
    val  phone: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "bank_url")
    val  url: String?
)

data class Country(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "country_alpha")
    val  alpha2: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "country_currency")
    val  currency: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "country_emoji")
    val  emoji: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "country_latitude")
    val  latitude: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "country_longitude")
    val  longitude: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "country_name")
    val  name: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "country_numeric")
    val  numeric: String?
)

data class Number(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_length")
    val  length: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "card_luhn")
    val  luhn: Boolean?
)
```

**CardDao**

```
@Dao
interface CardDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertCard(card : Card)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteCard(card : Card)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM card_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun getCards() : LiveData<List<Card>>
}
```

**Database**

```
@Database(
    entities = [Card::class],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class CardDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun cardDao() : CardDao
    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE : CardDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): CardDatabase {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    CardDatabase::class.java,
                    "app_database"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**dependencies**
Everything UP-TO-DATE

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    // for retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.11'

    // for coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3'

    // for viewModel
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.2"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-coroutines:2.1.0-alpha04"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2"
}
```

I have tried to use older dependencies and older versions of Kotlin. as I read these errors are caused by the older versions of room but they disappeared in the latest versions.